# Pandas filtering on dynamic columns with dynamic values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm having a pandas Dataframe and I want to perform filtering on that dataset dynamically.
Like

[image]

Now I have list of filters like:

```
{
  "Department Name": "Engineering",
  "Account ID": "511110"
}
```

Basically, In pandas if I want to get Total Sale for `Department Name: "Engineering"` and `Account ID: 511110`. then I have to mention these filtering parameters as

```
filtered_df = df.loc[(df["Department Name"] == "Engineering") & (df["Account ID"] == 511110)]
total_sales = filtered_df["Total Sales"].sum()
```

Now think about, if these filtering parameters are dynamic then we need to add filters in loop

```
for field_name in filters:
    filter_val = filters[field_name]
    df = df.loc[df[field_name]==filter_val

total_sales = df["Total Sales"].sum()
```

So I'm trying to find a way, where I can add all the filtering parameters as a list to pandas dataframe and it provides me filtered records. So I can apply other operations on that.

Thanks in Advance.